# What are all the possible types of fabricjs objects?

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

Looking through TS definition here I still can't seem to find all the possible types of fabric objects, I can't find a list of types on fabricJS documentation page either:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/06aceea74ca33b2217dcd9f5c53fd9cb1148ff62/types/fabric/fabric-impl.d.ts

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/docs/ <- look for the list of Classes on the left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list below is taken from http://fabricjs.com/docs/, although it appears that the official list is out of date so I've added the Textbox class.

- Line
- Circle
- Triangle
- Ellipse
- Rect
- Polyline
- Polygon
- Group
- Text
- IText
- Textbox
- Image
- Path
- PathGroup

Comment: Ok, I guess to clarify I wanted the string representations, I've noticed if I check the fabricObject.type for IText I will get the string `i-text` and for an image: `image` so I'm not sure if these map perfectly from the "Class Name" to the `fabricObject.type` string.